# Trying to postion Divs in webpage?

Tags: css, html

Im trying to position these so there are 2 rows of 3 "content boxes" but when trying to align them they just go everywhere. any help? thanks.

Code.

```
    .carbox {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: normal;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #363F48;
}
.carlisting {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(229, 238, 248, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(229, 238, 248, 1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(229, 238, 248, 1);
    border: 1px solid #e9edf2;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: #ffffff;
}
.toprow {
    height: 107px;
    border-bottom: lightgray 1px solid;
}
.carinfo {
    height: 107px;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
.carinfo .title {
    height: 53.5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height:53px;
}
.carinfo .price {
    height: 53.5px;
}
.carinfo .price span {
    color: white;
    height: 18px;
    width: 50px;
    padding:2px 4px;
    background-color: #363F48;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.btrow span {
    border-right: 1px lightgray solid;
    margin:5px 4px;
}
```

HTML (Note there is a container at the top that is margins ect.

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="carbox">
            <div class="carlisting">
                <div class="toprow">
                    <img height="107px" src="http://demo.swebdesignstudio.com/templates/carell/car_dealer/images/car-1.jpg" width="186px" />
                    <div class="carinfo"> 
                    <div class="title">Honda</div>
                    <div class="price"><span>£999.99</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="btrow">
                    <span>2012</span> <span>100bhp</span> <span>12,000mi</span>
                    <span>Manual</span> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carbox">
            <div class="carlisting">
                <div class="toprow">
                    <img height="107px" src="http://demo.swebdesignstudio.com/templates/carell/car_dealer/images/car-1.jpg" width="186px" />
                    <div class="carinfo"> 
                    <div class="title">Honda</div>
                    <div class="price"><span>£999.99</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="btrow">
                    <span>2012</span> <span>100bhp</span> <span>12,000mi</span>
                    <span>Manual</span> </div>
            </div>
<div class="carbox">
            <div class="carlisting">
                <div class="toprow">
                    <img height="107px" src="http://demo.swebdesignstudio.com/templates/carell/car_dealer/images/car-1.jpg" width="186px" />
                    <div class="carinfo"> 
                    <div class="title">Honda</div>
                    <div class="price"><span>£999.99</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="btrow">
                    <span>2012</span> <span>100bhp</span> <span>12,000mi</span>
                    <span>Manual</span> </div>
            </div>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="carbox">
            <div class="carlisting">
                <div class="toprow">
                    <img height="107px" src="http://demo.swebdesignstudio.com/templates/carell/car_dealer/images/car-1.jpg" width="186px" />
                    <div class="carinfo"> 
                    <div class="title">Honda</div>
                    <div class="price"><span>£999.99</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="btrow">
                    <span>2012</span> <span>100bhp</span> <span>12,000mi</span>
                    <span>Manual</span> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carbox">
            <div class="carlisting">
                <div class="toprow">
                    <img height="107px" src="http://demo.swebdesignstudio.com/templates/carell/car_dealer/images/car-1.jpg" width="186px" />
                    <div class="carinfo"> 
                    <div class="title">Honda</div>
                    <div class="price"><span>£999.99</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="btrow">
                    <span>2012</span> <span>100bhp</span> <span>12,000mi</span>
                    <span>Manual</span> </div>
            </div>
<div class="carbox">
            <div class="carlisting">
                <div class="toprow">
                    <img height="107px" src="http://demo.swebdesignstudio.com/templates/carell/car_dealer/images/car-1.jpg" width="186px" />
                    <div class="carinfo"> 
                    <div class="title">Honda</div>
                    <div class="price"><span>£999.99</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="btrow">
                    <span>2012</span> <span>100bhp</span> <span>12,000mi</span>
                    <span>Manual</span> </div>
            </div>
</section>
```

Screesnshot:

https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Screenshots/Screenshot%202014-04-23%2022.41.37.png?_subject_uid=15468544&w=AADDCyCb4DCHjvJkraYMb1RDu90iqHThnQV_z203Fit2UA

Comment: Here's a fiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/tG4KU/. Not sure exactly what you're referring to as a content box.

Comment: Proberly should of added this earlier, im trying to do somethng similar to this http://demo.swebdesignstudio.com/templates/carell/car_dealer/car-listing-1.html

Comment: Your problem is not fully closing out of your div's.
This is the same thing, but I was sure the carbox div closed.
http://jsfiddle.net/tG4KU/12/

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of missing `</div>`

Here is an example of your code. I used a percentage instead of a px value for the width.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kfg4L/

Comment: Hey! Thats much better! It was just a snippet of the area if that thats you mean? not the entire website? Im just comparing now, thanks so much!

Comment: No, you have missing </div> for a few of your .carbox divs. just go over your HTML and make sure each <div> has a corresponding </div>.. If this helped your problem please consider marking it as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem look like (aside from the unclosed divs as others have mentioned) that you have a fixed width on your elements so can only have "rows of 3 boxes" on very specific screen sizes that work with that pixel width.

Probably best changing to % width, e.g. `width:30%;margin-right:3%;` or similar to have a more responsive content structure - you will need to make sure within these boxes you aren't fixing width that break it though.